# Include a log file in a HTML page with SSI

Tags: nginx, ssi

I'm trying some stuff for the moment and now it's trying to display the content of a log file in a HTML page.

So, I add `ssi on;` in my Nginx `.conf` file and add this to the HTML page :

```
<!--#include file="../../../../var/log/nginx/logs.access.log" -->
```

The path is good but I'm always having this error :

> [an error occurred while processing the directive]

Would you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!--#include file=` in nginx is the same thing as `<!--# include virtual=`, so `../../../../var/log/nginx/logs.access.log` doesn't look like valid request.

But you can add location like this:

```
location = /logs.access.log {
    internal;
    root /var/log/nginx;
}
```

and use `<!--#include file="/logs.access.log" -->` accordingly.